# Ubuntu 16.04 no Launcher or Panel

Tags: 16.04, launcher, panel

It's now 2 days when I boot on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 the desktop has no Launcher or Panel. Ctrl+Alt+T doesn't work. I have to right-click for the terminal to appear which is also useless can't type anything. For me to test commands I have to use the tty with Ctrl+Alt+F1.

I have tried most of the commands shared here with success for the last 2 days am on the verge of reinstalling Ubuntu or just downgrading to Ubuntu 14. I have tried almost everything listed about unity and ccms. someone please help. I have shared my desktop:

[image]

Comment: When did this begin to occur? Was an upgrade run or and packages installed?

Comment: IF that doesn't help could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have a look at [these methods](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-unity-no-launcher-no-dash-in-ubuntu-12-10-quick-tip/) (if not already tried). Of particular note are the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install –reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
sudo shutdown -r now
```

If that doesn't solve it I guess a reinstall is in order. But it's always a good idea to take an image of your system while it is running well and is up to date. Then you'll never have to worry about reinstalls if anything goes wrong again. Only ever taken me a few minutes to restore from an image with  everything back to normal.

Comment: This worked for me and restored my menus, however the comand ```rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1``` deleted all my files so guys back-up your data before running the command